# Distributed cache synchronization on multiple service instances using Guava Cache

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava

I am using **Guava Cache** in my services to cache database, and I am using REST calls to *invalidate/refresh* cache contents. My setup contains deployment of 10 distributed instances of my `service`.

What are the best practices to maintain **synchronization** across caches on multiple instances? Ideally if I send a cache `update` REST call to 1 instance then I would want it to trigger the same call on the remaining 9 instances.

I want to avoid remote cache solutions to avoid additional REST calls and associated network latency.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a distributed cache systems like [Redis](https://redis.io/), then what you are looking at is having another endpoint in you service layer that sends/receive REST calls from another service instances (along with cache value plus cache meta data) as soon as cache invalidation(eviction) or TTL refresh event happens to update your in-memory Guava cache layer.

Answer (score 0):

Guava Cache has nothing to do with distributed applications, its in-memory for single JVM by definition.

If you need to do a distributed cache consider:

1. Using other tools (like Hazelcast for example or [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/in-memory-cache.html).
2. Use Redis - it will store a single copy of data on Redis service but the query to it is very fast, although not as fast as in-memory call. However if you're using caching, the chances are that the data is updated rarely but gets queried often, so maybe you can use redis in conjunction with some in-memory map + send a message to all instances (pub-sub) once the cache on one instance gets updated. Even in Redis there is a pub sub that will work for this kind of job, or you can use messaging systems like RabbitMq, ActiveMQ, etc. if you already have them.
3. Use database + messaging - similarly to the "2" however the single copy of data will be stored in the database.